# problems with java path and total commander

Tags: java, path, total-commander

I am facing a very strange problem regarding total commander and java path (Total Commander 7.56a - Windows 7 64bit).

After updating my java from 6 to 7, and pointing all my environmental variables to the right direction, I am having the following strange behavior.

When I open a command line (not through total commander), the following commands print:

- `java -version prints java version "1.7.0_07"` (expected)
- `javac -version prints javac 1.7.0_07` (expected)

BUT when I **open a cmd through total commander** (type cmd in total commander's bottom command box), I get the following:

- `java -version prints java version "1.6.0_22"` (**my previous java version**)
- `javac -version prints javac 1.7.0_07 (the correct one!)

Any hints?

Comment: I think it is better you post your question in forum for Totalcommander. http://www.ghisler.ch/board/index.php?language=english is the link to that.

Comment: Difficult to register :( "Sorry, we no longer accept gmail addresses, because too many spammers use it. This created so many mails that all our e-mails now go to the Spam folder on GMail."

Comment: It exists more than one email provider at the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I also had to update my 32-bit version of java, since total commander is using my 32-bit version of cmd.

Thanks @reporter for pointing me out the forum of total commander. You can find the complete thread of my question [here](http://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=255020#255020)

Comment: Hi alexandros, you can accept your own answer (since two days have passed).